# Ubuntu USB Wifi

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

First off, I know there are a lot of discussions about similar issues here, but I've tried a number of things and am still struggling.  I'm also a new Linux/Ubuntu user, so forgive my ignorance...

I have an HP laptop where the wifi chip went out years ago.  I've been using a Edimax EW-7811un since then on Windows 7 and then 10 with no issues.

However, on installing Ubuntu 19.10 in dual boot setup, the wifi hasn't been working.

I've tried instructions similar to those [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390919), where you clone a git repo, run some commands, and reboot, but nothing's worked so far.  I'm sure by now I've installed a number of random drivers, which probably isn't helping...

Anyway, here are some hopefully helpful diagnostics:

```
##### iwconfig
username@user-ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
wlx801f02bed5a1  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.


#### rfkill list
username@user-ubuntu:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes


#### lsmod
username@user-ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep rtl
# returns nothing
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit -- also just tried this to no avail

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```